# modifying data that has already been queued java

Tags: java, queue

Is it in any way possible to modify objects that have already been added in a queue? (e.g. Let's assume i want to implement a FIFO queue with a list of transactions) I don't want/need to change to order of the transactions in the queue, i only want to update some quantities and if the available quantity is depleted remove the transaction from the queue.   I've checked peek / deque etc but that doesn't seem to  provide the wanted behavior

Comment: If you already have a reference to the Object you want to modify it'll also be modified in the queue, as the queue will reference the same Object. If you don't, then you need to provide a way to find and access specific Objects in your queue. A `Collection` implementing the `Queue` interface in Java will allow you to search the `Queue` using it's `Iterator` implementation.

Comment: yes having a custom implementation might be the way to go, as having the references would be unlikely.thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, I made a mistake.  It seems to be possible to get a reference to the object through peek and modify the content.

e.g.

```
Queue<Transaction> bought_fifo = new LinkedList<Transaction>();
Transaction tr2 = bought_fifo.peek();
tr2.setPrice(new BigDecimal(1000000000L));
```

As I only need to adapt quantities in a FIFO manner and move to the next transaction if the quantity is not sufficient, it solves my need.
For more advanced use (random changes in data) you could indeed build your own.

Answer (score 0):

In java every variable that hols an object actually only holds a reference to that object. So if you still have your object somewhere you can edit it. Example:

```
Object test= new Object();

ArrayList<Object> list =new ArrayList();

list.add(test)

//if you change the object test now and then take the object from the list it will be changed
```